# Why isn't postgres prompting me about a new user?

Tags: postgresql

I'm following these instructions to get postgres working with rails on Windows 7:

> Run "Start Command Prompt with Ruby" then...
>
> 1. createuser -U postgres -P NewUserName
> 2. When it prompts for a password for new role, assign it a new password.
> 3. No, the new role should not be a superuser.
> 4. Yes, the new role should be allowed to create databases.
> 5. No, the new role should not be allowed to create more new roles.
> 6. Enter the postgresPWD you made when we installed PostgreSQL.

But this isn't happening. After I run #1, it asks me for a password, then skips straight to 5. This is completely screwing me over! Where did 2 through 4 go?

So then I tried doing it manually with `createuser -s -U postgres -d -r` (I have to do `-U postgres` because otherwise it asks for a password for a user that seems to be based on my Windows account, and no password I give it is successful...I tried fixing this by changing pg_hba.conf and then NOTHING worked)....so anyway I tried doing it manually and it was successful, but then I tried `createdb newdb_name` and it said `createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "{my windows account}"`.

So I guess I could `createdb` as `postgres`, but then my rails commands to `rake db:create` would still fail. I need the active account to have full rights so that I can keep doing rails work.

I'm becoming really miserable about this. Please help...

Comment: I got everything working once I figured out how to make handy use of the pgAdmin interface, but via Windows command line this is still all very baffling to me.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: I've reverted your edits because they're removing way too much and loosing half the meaning. Not OK with that at all.

Comment: @Aerovistae Ok, then I'll vote to close. I've voted to close this question for being **Too Broad** `createuser` prompts have *nothing* to do with database you're connecting too, and as the chosen answer says: they're *"two distinct questions"*. Please consider breaking the question a part (or accepting the edit to refine the scope).

Comment: You realize this is a 5 year old question, right? What difference does it make to anyone whether this is open or closed? It already had an accepted answer.

Comment: @Aerovistae we have to weight out the value of the question in perpetuity. 3,693 people have seen this. Fact is that's a lot of stuff not relevant to the prompt that shouldn't be there imho (or in the opinion of the Daniel unless he's advocating for compound questions). I don't think it's a very high quality question to be burdening those searching for this problem with what database they should be connecting to, so I tried to clean it up and fix the issue. If you want to accept the edits, I'll give you the upvote. Until then, StackOverflow has better more terse material on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that there are two distinct questions here.

1. Why don't the `createuser` instructions apply?

   It's because they apply to PostgreSQL 9.1 or older, and not the newest versions.
   `createuser` now has a new flag `--interactive`. Per [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-createuser.html):

   > `--interactive` Prompt for the user name if none is specified on the command line, and also prompt for whichever of the options -d/-D,
   >   -r/-R, -s/-S is not specified on the command line. (This was the default behavior up to PostgreSQL 9.1.)

   So by adding this flag you'll get back to the behavior described by the tutorial.
2. Once the user is created, why does `createdb` fails with a password authentication problem?

   It's because you're not using your newly created user to create the database, although it's what would seem to make sense in this context.

   Generally with all PostgreSQL command line tools, when a user is not specified on the command line, the OS user is assumed instead (but it's only useful when there happens to be a database user named after the OS user, otherwise that may unfortunately be a source of confusion).

Anyway, instead of `createdb newdb_name`, try:

```
createdb -U newusername newdb_name
```

Then you should be asked for the password of `newusername` that you created in the step above.

Technically `createdb` has to connect to a database (`template1` in this case) to be able to create another database, because this is done by a SQL statement and no SQL can be issued when you're not connected to a database in the first place.

Also by doing this `newusername` will be the database owner of `newdb_name`, that will give it full over control over it and is probably what your application needs.

Comment: Fantastic answer, very insightful, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

First, let's understand [how `createuser` works](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-createuser.html), run this command and take a look at the results:

```
> createuser --help
```

Will you see a lot of information, by those the most important for you now is the following...

This one is what makes PostgreSQL ask for a password for this new user:

```
-P, --pwprompt            assign a password to new role
```

This one is the one that will make this user able to create a new database (notice you didn't used it):

```
-d, --createdb            role can create new databases
```

At the bottom, you will have a group of arguments:

```
Connection options:
  -h, --host=HOSTNAME       database server host or socket directory
  -p, --port=PORT           database server port
  -U, --username=USERNAME   user name to connect as (not the one to create)
  -w, --no-password         never prompt for password
  -W, --password            force password prompt
```

These ones are used to connect to PostgreSQL's instance, which means that, to create a new user you will have first to connect to PostgreSQL using an already existent user that is able to create another. On a default installation the only user you have is `postgres`, so to connect you have to use it as `-U postgres`. Depending on your `pg_hba.conf` configuration, the `createuser` utility will ask for the password of `postgres` user.

With all these information, you should be able to know how to create your new user:

```
> createuser -U postgres -e -P -d NewUserName
```

OBS: `-e` is not necessary, but is good to learn what is happening behinde the scenes.

Afeter that all, you probably can create a new database using `rake db:create`. Perhaps you will need to edit [`pg_hba.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html), but I think this is a new topic.